# Why are local JSON files not fetched in React.JS?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to fetch some data like this.

```
function ImageJersey() {
  
  var JSXArray = [];
  fetch("./jsonapi/run_results_jerseys.json")
    .then((data) => {
      return data.json();
    })
    .then((dataJson) => {
      console.log(dataJson);
      JSXArray.push(<div> {dataJson} </div>);
    });

  return <div>{JSXArray}</div>;
```

If I change the `res.json()` to `res.text()`, the **public/index.html** file of React is  generated instead of the targeted JSON file.

Comment: remove the starting dot in fetch url.

Comment: my guess is that you are not finding the json file and are getting 404 response page. which you are displaying when you do res.text()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is the file hasnt been fetch yet. Fetching is async action and needs to be put inside useEffect()